# JSONP python script

Tags: javascript, python, json, proxy, jsonp

I've been playing around with the code (HTML2Canvas) from here: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas

It's a client side Javascript tool to convert a HTML page to a canvas element.

Its uses a proxy to fetch the HTML from a remote site, it makes an Ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
       data: {
         xhr2:false,
         url:urlParts.href

         },
         url: "http://html2canvas.appspot.com",
         dataType: "jsonp",
         success: function(html) {
```

This results in the following, when requesting yahoo.com as the sample URL, url being requested:

```
http://html2canvas.appspot.com/?callback=jQuery162020564090818326575_1311846010895&xhr2=false&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F&_=1311846201150
```

What I want to do is roll my own JSONP proxy which I can point my copy of the code to. Trouble is I have no idea where to start.

The JSONP that is returned (I won't copy it all) begins like this:

```
jQuery162020564090818326575_1311846010895("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en-US\" class=\"y-fp-bg y-fp-pg-grad  bkt701\" style=\
```

So the HTML is escaped and wrapped in a callback.

I'd like to create a Python script that works along the exact same lines and generates the exact same output.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for creating a Python JSONP proxy which would generate similar output? It doesn't have to be Python, I'm just referencing that as it's what is currently used.

Comment: Can't you just strip off the callback - something like `jsonp.partition("(")[2].rstrip(")")` - and then do as you like with the string that's left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the source up for the python proxy at https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas-proxy. Be warned though, the script will still go through changes which will most likely break the proxy.